# SQL: How to count number of each item within categories in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that shows the name of a store and the individual city where the orders come from, taken from a json query in PostgreSQL. It is based off of a survey, in which we also see how many times the survey is viewed and how many responses there are. I am trying to create another column in the table which basically counts the number of orders from each city for each store. 
An example list is shown here, where the name of the store is the left hand side, and the city is the right hand side:

```
 1. Glossier   |   New York       |    7    |    6
 2. Glossier   |   New York       |    7    |    6
 3. Glossier   |   Chicago        |    7    |    6
 4. Glossier   |   Boston         |    7    |    6
 5. Glossier   |   New York       |    7    |    6
 6. Glossier   |   Chicago        |    7    |    6
 7. Sephora    |   New York       |    10   |    8
 8. Sephora    |   Baltimore      |    10   |    8
 9. Sephora    |   New York       |    10   |    8
 10. Sephora   |   Boston         |    10   |    8
 11. Sephora   |   New York       |    10   |    8
 12. Sephora   |   Baltimore      |    10   |    8
 13. Sephora   |   Chicago        |    10   |    8
 14. Sephora   |   San Francisco  |    10   |    8
```

The code I have been using is:

```
WITH
    cities AS (
        SELECT context->>'city' AS city,
        context->>'shop_id' AS shopid
        FROM public.analytics_events
        ),
    views AS (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT ON (ref_id) ref_id,
            CASE WHEN context->>'order_total' IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE cast(context->>'order_total' AS NUMERIC)
            END AS total,
                context->>'shop_id' AS shop_id
        FROM public.analytics_events
        ),
    view_counts AS (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ref_id) AS views, SUM(total)
            AS volume, shop_id
            FROM views
            GROUP BY shop_id
        ),
    response_counts AS (
            SELECT COUNT(survey_responses.id) AS responses,
            surveys.shop_id AS shop_id, surveys.question, 
            surveys.id AS surveyid
            FROM public.survey_responses
            LEFT JOIN public.surveys
            ON surveys.id = survey_responses.survey_id
            GROUP BY surveys.shop_id, surveys.question, surveyid
        )
    SELECT
        name,
        CASE WHEN views IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE views END,
        CASE WHEN responses IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE responses END,
        city,
        COUNT(*)
    FROM public.shops
    LEFT JOIN view_counts ON shops.id = view_counts.shop_id
    LEFT JOIN response_counts ON shops.id = response_counts.shop_id
    LEFT JOIN cities on shops.id = cities.shopid
    GROUP BY name, city;
```

However, I am now stuck on how to create the next step.

Comment: What is an "order"?  What results do you want?

Comment: You really need to tell us which database you are using, as JSON APIs vary greatly.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you simply want `group by`:

```
WITH cities AS (
      SELECT context->>'city' AS city, context->>'shop_id' AS shopid
      FROM analytics
     )
SELECT name, city, COUNT(*)
FROM shops LEFT JOIN
     cities 
     ON shops.id = cities.shopid
GROUP BY name, city;
```

Comment: Thought this wouldn't matter but I'm trying to utilize data from survey views and responses at the same time, and I keep getting the error "column "view_counts.views" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function", not sure how to account for that

Comment: @JuliaMartin . . . This query has no reference to `view_counts` or `view_counts.views`.  Perhaps you should ask another question.